# How to add data to OBJECT from Wordpress get_results in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, json, wordpress, associative-array

Seems really easy, but I can't seem to figure it out...

I have a simple line that gets mysql results through wordpress like this:

```
$sql_results = $wpdb->get_results($sql_phrase);
```

Then I parse it as JSON and echo it: `json_encode($sql_results);`

However, **I want to add other data before I parse it as JSON.** But I'm not sure how.

`$sql_results` basically gets me a list of post ID's, title and category.
It looks like this in var_dump (this is just the first row):

```
array(1)
{
[0]=> object(stdClass)#2737 (7)
    {
    ["ID"]=> string(4) "2700"
    ["post_title"]=> string(18) "The compact helmet"
    ["category"]=> string(5) "Other"
    }
}
```

Now to start with something easy, I'd like all associative arrays inside the object to have the extra key-value. I tried the following but got an error:
500 Internal error.

```
foreach($sql_search as $key => $value)
{
    $value['pic_img'] = "test";
    $sql_search[$key]=$value;       
}
$result=$sql_search;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$sql_results = array(1)
{
[0]=> object(stdClass)#2737 (7)
    {
    ["ID"]=> string(4) "2700"
    ["post_title"]=> string(18) "The compact helmet"
    ["category"]=> string(5) "Other"
    }
}
    foreach($sql_results as $key=>$value)
    { 
        $value->solution = 'good';
        $sql_results[$key]=$value;

    }
$result=$sql_results;
var_dump($result);
```

Comment: Man, you're a PHP god! I never understand the difference between `$str->$val` and `$str=>$val` and `$str[$val]`.
But this fixed my problem! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
$test = array ( array("ID"=>"35", "name"=>"Peter", "age"=>"43"), 

array("ID"=>"34", "name"=>"James", "age"=>"19"), array("ID"=>"31", "name"=>"Joe", "age"=>"40") );

    foreach($test as $key=>$value)
    { 
        $value['solution'] = 'good';
        $test[$key]=$value;

    }
$result=$test;
var_dump($result);
```

Comment: I tried this to test but it didn't work:
    $test = array
  (
  array("ID"=>"35", "name"=>"Peter", "age"=>"43"),
  array("ID"=>"34", "name"=>"James", "age"=>"19"),
  array("ID"=>"31", "name"=>"Joe", "age"=>"40")
  );
 foreach($test as $key=>$value){
  $value['solution'] = 'good';
 }
 $result = $test;
 var_dump($result);
 echo "<br><br>";
 $result = json_encode($result);
 echo $result;

Comment: Please refer above new answer for your comment containing code.

Comment: WisdmLabs You wanna know something weird?
It works with the test object. But once I replace the `$test` with `$sql_search` then it gives me a `500 internal error`... Did you ever had this before?

Comment: Thanks! I shared an example of one of the rows inside `$sql_search` parsed as JSON in the question. And at the bottom I added what I am testing.